# Link facebook data to currently logged in user with Passport.js

Tags: node.js, express, oauth, passport.js

I'm using passport.js and I'm wounding if I can link a facebook id to a logged in user's account. Something like this:

```
passport.use( new FacebookStrategy({
        consumerKey: ---
        consumerSecret: ---
        callbackURL: "http://mycallback"
    },
    function(token, tokenSecret, profile, done) {
        if (user is logged in)
            user = User.addfacebookId(user, profile.id)
            done(user);
        }
    }   
));
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There's a few ways to approach this, but I think one of the most straight-forward is to use the `passReqToCallback` option.  With that enabled, `req` becomes the first argument to the verify callback, and from there you can check to see if `req.user` exists, which means the user is already logged in.  At that point, you can associate the user with Facebook profile details and supply the same user instance to the done callback.  If `req.user` does not exist, just handle it as usual.

For example:

```
passport.use(new FacebookStrategy({
    clientID: ---
    clientSecret: ---
    callbackURL: "http://mycallback"
    passReqToCallback: true
  },
  function(req, accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
    if (req.user)
      // user is already logged in.  link facebook profile to the user
      done(req.user);
    } else {
      // not logged in.  find or create the user based on facebook profile
    }
  }   
));
```

Comment: That's perfect Jared thank you... and thank you for saving me from everyauth :)

Comment: thank you very much, I also had this problem. this passReqToCallback solves everything! thank you!